# Survival analysis per group for recurrent events

Tags: r, survival, recurrent-events

I am new to survival analysis, but I have a task to find the survival of groups that contain recurrent events. Without taking any predictor into account. Each group (ID) may have the same subjects, for instance the subject 22303 appears in both ID 1 and 2.

[image]

Given that i want to find the survival for each group i was thinking to use the coxph function with ~strata(ID) in my model, thus the results will be stratified by the ID. However, i would like to apply the AG model or PWP model as well.

Does anyone knows based on the structure of the input dataset the R code for the implementation of these two models?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It does not become clear what you want to do/compare. Do you want to compare two groups, estimate a rate,  etc. Please be more precise in your requests.